# SDL_GL_DeleteContext after SDL_Quit?

Tags: opengl, sdl-2

- Is it safe to delete your **OpenGL** context after you shutdown your subsystems with **SDL2**?

The documentation is really vague. The code in question are these two statements:

```
SDL_GL_DeleteContext(glcontext);
SDL_Quit();
```

I thought that it would be alot more responsive if the window closes instantly, and all the other cleanup happens in the background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you've told in last sentence could be achieved with `SDL_HideWindow`.

As for `SDL_Quit` - since it 'cleans up all initialized subsystems', and `SDL_Init` documentation says it 'must be called before using any other SDL function', you shouldn't call any SDL function after `SDL_Quit`. Even if it will work on some systems, there is no guarantee for others (or future versions).